# Next link on node page based on its taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

So here is what I'd like to achieve:

I'd like to put a Next link to every content of a type, that links to the next content with the same taxonomy term.

So for examle if I have A, B and C products with the term 'clothing' on them, I need a link A product that points to B, one link on B that points to C and so on.

How is this possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only in Alpha but the [Treewalk Previous / Next](http://drupal.org/project/treewalk) module appears to have that functionality:

> Previous/Next (Back/Forward) links for entity and other pages, that allow to visit them in a sequence.
>
> Unlike with the existing back/forward module, the sequence of items (entities etc) is not based on a view, but on hierarchical information already present in your site.
>
> - It provides a configurable block with prev/next links based on menu trees. The block is named "Treewalk Prev/Next (Menu)"
> - It provides Display suite fields with prev/next links based on entityreference / taxonomy_term_reference fields. The ds fields are named as "Treewalk Prev/Next (...)".

I've never used it but it might at least be a starting point to implement the logic yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Flippy](http://drupal.org/project/flippy) module for this.

> Flippy is an ultra-simple module that generates previous/next pagers for content types. On the Node type administration screen, you can turn Flippy on or off
>   for each content type. It'll generate a unique pager for each content type, so you can page through Articles or page through Blog posts, but you can't page
>   through all nodes on the site.

Comment: Does that module work based on a vocabulary (per the question)?

Comment: @Clive: I am not sure but we can alter its query in our custom module..
:)

Comment: Flippy doesn't seem to be providing sorting content based on taxonomy terms.

Comment: @BálintDeáki: open this module and alter its query using hook_query_alter in your custom module